# How to estimate system resource usage of a SparseArray?

Tags: sparse-arrays

Build a 100.000.000 by 10 element SparseArray.
Fill position 1/1 and 100.000.000/10 with a value 999.999.999.999.999.

```
num = 999999999999999;  
idSparse = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> num, {100000000, 10} -> num}];
```

Look for RAM usage.

```
ByteCount[idSparse] 
976
```

Export it to a file

```
Export["idSparse.rsa", idSparse];
```

See the disk usage.

```
FileByteCount["idSparse.rsa"]  
205000360
```

Is it OK like that?
Two elements only occupied.
For file usage is very high compared with RAM usage.

Comment: I can't reproduce your observations: as one would wish and expect, the file seems to be the same (small) size no matter how large the array nominally is. I tried in version 9.0.1. Which version are you using?

Comment: The two numbers 976 and 205000360 are mixed up.  . .Sorry.  .  .So file size is small and RAM usage is large.

Comment: There is definitely something strange here, and the memory usage is much higher in version 9 than in previous versions. This would be a good question if you would edit it to focus on the memory usage rather than the file size. When you do so, you'll have my upvote.